# resize image email order

Tags: magento-1.9, email

Good evening, I add a function to insert a picture in the order confirmation email Magento 1.9

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel('catalog/product_media_config')->getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail()); ?>" 
 alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>"/>
```

But I can't resize it

Example : getMediaUrl($_product->getThumbnail())->resize(150); ?>" 
 alt="getName() ?>"/>

could you help me ?`

Answer (score 1):

Try below code:

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(150); ?>" alt="<?php echo $_item->getName() ?>"/>
```

I hope this helps!